# My 8 month old puppy won't eat

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, eating

Raja, my pup, and I just moved back to college and she won't eat. When I give her her food she just noses it until its everywhere and keeps nosing it until it's wedged behind my desk. There was another dog where we were staying, could she be depressed?

Comment: Does she eat anything at all, like treats? Does she drink a normal amount of water and defecate normally? Is she playfull and energetic or lethargic and fatigued? Do you give her wet or dry food? If there are any indications that her behavior could have a physical / medical reason, you should let a vet check her.

Comment: how long has this been going on,not eating.

Comment: It's only been a day, her energy is normal, she is drinking water, and she has yet to poop.

Answer (score 1):

Try offering her absolute favorite food, or a couple hot dog pieces (which dogs seem to find irresistible). Then take her for a **really long walk**. Keep her moving for at least a half hour. The movement will help her "do what she needs to do".  If nothing happens after a half hour (or more) of activity, talk to her Veterinarian about your concerns.